# pdf highlighting in solr

Tags: pdf, solr, highlight

I have indexed PDF on my Solr. and i have made a search engine. now i want to highlighting it below my PDF title. like google one.
The structure i looking for is :

1. PDF Title
2. URL/path of PDF
3. Desc (Highlighting in solr) and the word you search is bolded.

but in the solr query result, the metadata is not contain the pdf content. what should i put in the hl.fl ? and what code i need to change in solrconfig.xml and manage-schema ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [solr highlighting like google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432852/solr-highlighting-like-google)

Comment: You asked the same question earlier, and my last comment there was about how you make sure that you're indexing the content so that it's stored in a field by itself. What has changed and what have you tried to warrant a new question?

Comment: yes it was me. my last change is the first structure, i can make href for "the PDF title". i've tried looking for fmap.content=text in all reference in stackoverflow and pdf from apache, but i've no idea.

Comment: When you're indexing content through the ExtractingRequestHandler, the content of the PDF file is put into a field named `content`. If you don't have a field named that defined, you'll have to map it to a field that you have defined - or define a `content` field. `fmap.content=text` indexes the PDF content into a field named `text` instead.

Comment: i do have add this code to the solrconfig.xml :
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

Comment: Sorry, but `_text_` wont work, as it's not set to `stored` by default. `<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>` - if the field is not set to stored, its actual textual contents will not be saved, and you can't retrieve the field's value.

Comment: sorry for late reply. i've made change to the schema, the _text_ in schema is "indexed="false"" then i change it to true. and it works. now the next problem is, how to print the highlight in php, i will try my best for this. thanks for your big help